# easybitcoin sendfrom not working to errors

Tags: bitcoind, php

When I try to send bitcoins via `move` or `sendfrom` nothing happends, I dont het any errors. I use a very simple script:

```
try {
    $_SESSION['message'] = $bitcoin->sendfrom($_COOKIE['login_user'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['amount']);
}
    catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I don't get any output in the session message and no error. The user cookie contains and existing user in bitcoind with enough money. POST address contains a valid address. POST ammount contains 0.0008. Does someone know what is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors? Did you try `$bitcoin->error` ?

Comment: I already tried.